# How do I get a dict of Python class attributes (not an instance)?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to access attributes in a class so I can change them dynamically.

I have seen answers on this site that suggest the class's `__dict__` will provide this, as I tried with this code:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.description = ''
        self.weight = ''
        self.volume = ''

print(Item.__dict__)

{'__module__': '__main__', '__init__': <function Item.__init__ at 0x0000026F3F5988C8>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Item' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Item' objects>, '__doc__': None}
```

It seems I want to access `Item.__dict__.['__dict__']`but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Try,`Item().__dict__`. `Item.__dict__`  will only get the `class` attribute, not the `instance` attributes, which is what you are asking for :)

Comment: @hansolo, well spotted :-) I think that's worth making into an answer.

Comment: Actually, I want to change the value of the class attribute.

Comment: `Item.__dict__` is the answer to question on the title. What exactly do you want?

Comment: @Buffersnuff But your Item class doesn't have any class attributes. name, description, etc are instance attributes. If you wanted a class attribute, you'd define them outside of the `__init__`. For example, `class Item: <newline> <tab> foo=1 <newline> <tab> def __init__(self): <rest of class goes here>`.

Comment: @Kevin Someone beat me in the answer section :)

Comment: Thanks guys I am straightened out now. I feel dumb but I really appreciate the good help.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, in order to see instance attributes (rather than class attributes), you'll have to instantiate an object of that type. However rather than using the `__dict__` attribute, it is preferred to use the builtin [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) function.

```
item = Item()
items_attrs = vars(item)
```

This does the same thing under the hood, but appears a bit more Pythonic.

---

You could also define a [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) attribute on the class. This will change the behavior of the class (and its objects) in what is perhaps an unwanted way, but allows you easy access to the information you're interested in. Notably, this behavior changes:

> Without a `__dict__` variable, instances cannot be assigned new variables not listed in the `__slots__` definition. Attempts to assign to an unlisted variable name raises `AttributeError`. If dynamic assignment of new variables is desired, then add `'__dict__'` to the sequence of strings in the `__slots__` declaration.

```
class Item(object):
    __slots__ = ['name',
        'description',
        'weight',
        'volume']

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.description = ''
        self.weight = ''
        self.volume = ''

Item_attrs = Item.__slots__
item = Item()
item_attrs = item.__slots__

assert item_attrs == Item_attrs
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be confused between class and instance variables. In the following modification of your code, `classvar` is a class variable:

```
class Item:
    classvar = 'foo'

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.description = ''
        self.weight = ''
        self.volume = ''
```

Now `Item.__dict__` will contain `classvar`. But instance variables are not created until the class is instantiated:

```
i1 = Item()
print(i1.__dict__())  # will contain 'name', 'description' etc.
```

However, why would you want to play around with `__dict__`? It is only needed for some code introspection tricks. You can access class and instance variables simply by the dot notation:

```
print(Item.classvar)
i1 = Item()
print(i1.name)
```

Comment: Now that you've clarified this for me, I won't need to mess with `__dict__`. Thanks a bunch.